# Unauthorized error in GAE SDK, but it works once deployed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am running this code in a small example:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

class TestB(base_handler.TRNHandler):
    #...
    def post(self):
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                           app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        #...
```

If I deploy this code everything works as expected. But when I run it locally (SDK), I get an error: Unauthorized: 401 Invalid Credentials. What's happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a pretty strong guess, although I can't be sure without seeing your exact logs and whatnot.

The google.cloud library is smart about authorization. It uses a thing called "application default credentials." If you run that code on App Engine or on a GCE instance, the code will be able to figure out which service account is associated with that instance and authorize itself with the credentials of that account.

However, when you run the program locally, the library has no way of knowing which credentials to use, and so it just makes calls anonymously. Your bucket probably hasn't granted anonymous users access (which is good), and so the call fails with a 401.

You can, however, register credentials locally with the gcloud command:

```
$> gcloud auth application-default login
```

Run that, and the library will use whatever credentials you've used to log in for a while. Alternatively, you could also make sure that the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` points to a service account's JSON key file.

There's a bunch of documentation on exactly how [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#howtheywork) pick a credential.

Alternately, if you'd prefer to specify auth right in the program, [you can do that too](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/google-cloud-auth.html#service-accounts):

```
storage = Storage.from_service_account_json('/path/to/key_file.json')
```

Comment: I tried using the gcloud command, but I still got the Unauthorized error. I also added: env_variables:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: secrets/trn-test2-fc647b4d3b1a.json but it only changed the error to 403 Caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket app_default_bucket. Same result with the last method. Maybe there is another problem?

Comment: That's progress, believe it or not. The 403 means that your call has been successfully authenticated as your account, but the account does not have permission on the bucket. The string "app_default_bucket" is interesting, lemme think about that

Comment: Okay, here's my new theory for you. When running locally in a development server, the call "get_default_gcs_bucket_name()" returns a constant string, "app_default_bucket", rather than the actual name of your GCS app engine bucket. The idea is that you'd then write to a local fake version of GCS for testing. But the library you're using does do app engine fakes; it tries to contact the real GCS, and there is no real bucket "app_default_bucket" that you have access to. I would suggest replacing the function call with the correct name of the bucket.

Comment: Thanks, now I've made some progress. You were right, there was no "app_default_bucket" (although that's what I used with cloudstorage). I used client.list_buckets() which gave me two names: trn-test2.appspot.com and staging.trn-test2.appspot.com. If I use any of those as a bucket name it works, but it uploads the images to the cloud instead of staying in the the local development space, which is what I was expecting. Is there a way for it to "upload" to the development server (the one you can see in the Blobstore viewer) or should I just use the staging bucket?

Comment: Yeah, the problem here is that the "cloudstorage" library knows about the app engine development server and the provided local fake version of GCS, but the gcloud-python library, while smarter in many other ways, doesn't. I would probably suggest just using your staging bucket if possible.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you very much for your help!